# Having a problem with While Loop VBA in Access

Tags: vba, ms-access

I'm stuck on how to make this loop work. Users scan in parts used for repairs, It's supposed to have one OrderID for each PartNum and than a SerialNum is used to sort what parts were all used in that repair. It will correctly reduce the inventoryqty on the record that is selected when the button is pushed, but will not reduce the inventory on the rest of the OrderID's inlucded for that SerialNum.

Including an image so it might make more sense, when pushing the button now it would only reduce Test1 but not the others.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/FGyAG.jpg

Really appreciate any input, I'm stuck on this. Thank you.

```
    Option Compare Database
    
    Private Sub ChangeInventory(PartNum As String, Qty As Long)
    Dim db As Database
    Dim rs As Recordset
    Set db = CurrentDb
    Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT * From PartsT where PartNum='" & Forms!CustomerXPartF!PartNum & "'")
    rs.Edit
    rs!InventoryQty = rs!InventoryQty + Qty
    rs.Update
    rs.Close
    db.Close
    Set rs = Nothing
    Set db = Nothing
    End Sub

Private Function AdjustInventory() As Boolean

Dim CurrentProductQty As Long

Dim db As Database
Dim rs As Recordset
Set db = CurrentDb
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT * From CustomerXPartT where OrderID =" & OrderID)
While Not rs.EOF
    CurrentProductQty = Nz(DLookup("InventoryQty", "PartsT", "PartNum='" & rs!PartNum & "'"))
    ChangeInventory rs!PartNum, rs!Qty * -1
    rs.MoveNext
Wend
    rs.Close
    db.Close
    Set rs = Nothing
    Set db = Nothing
End Function

Private Sub Command8_Click()
    AdjustInventory
End Sub
```

Comment: Why is the CustomerXPartT qualified "where OrderID"?  If you select one row (highlight it) and then press command8, the rs will return only one row.  Put a breakpoint on While Not rs.EOF and then step thru.  I expect only one row was returned and the rest of the orders were not selected because of the Where...

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what you mean. Are you saying the SQL statement is incorrect? If so, what can it change to? I don't have much experience with recordsets but that's the only way I've learned to do those.

Comment: What do you want to select? 1 order, or all 3 orders?  If one order, then keep "where OrderID =" & OrderID", or if all 3 orders, then remove the where clause.

Comment: Saving calculated data, especially aggregate data, is usually a bad idea. Calculate inventory balance from transaction records when needed. http://allenbrowne.com/AppInventory.html

Comment: I want to process all of the orders together then I can lock them all and complete the repair costs. I changed the statement to ("SELECT * From CustomerXPartT") and now it still doesn't always seem to take the correct amount from all parts, I did the imaged parts at 5 qty a piece and had it reduce inventory on just the first part by 45. It appears that it's taking the quantity for all Qty in the table not just on the form. See here https://imgur.com/a/koKMKuL . Have any other ideas how I can only process the current serial number's order but all at once?

Comment: Thanks for the tip June, I'll look into that in the meantime.